# Ruby MongoDB combine $ne and $or

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a query using the MongoDB drive in Ruby, where `$elements` is my cursor. I want to say that the `x` value can be anything except for 1, 2 and 3.

Here's what I've tried.

```
$elements.find({ "x" => {"$and" => {"$ne" => 1, "$ne" => 2, "$ne" => 3}} }).to_a
```

But `$and` is apparently not a valid operator. So then I tried this.

```
$elements.find({ "x" => {"$ne" => {"$or" => [1, 2, 3]}} }).to_a
```

But that just let all the elements with `x`=1 through anyways.

How to I accomplish what I want? Also, a link to where I might find a tutorial or some documentation would be appreciated, so that I can help myself next time.

Comment: `$and` is pefectly valid and does exist, you might be running an old MongoDB is it says it is not, though it is not valid like that

Comment: Yeah, the error message is a little ambiguous, but it is good to note that I should always run `sudo gem update` before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
$elements.find({ "x" => {"$nin" => [1, 2, 3]} }).to_a
```

About documentation... http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/

Comment: My mistake here was not consulting the MongoDB docs because they weren't Ruby specific. I'll keep in mind next time that it doesn't take much effort to convert `$nin: [1, 2, 3]` to `"$nin" => [1, 2, 3]`.